# Surinder Singh route at the airport

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, surinder-singh

I am a UK national and my spouse is from Argentina. We have been living in Europe for over 3 years and we are relocating back to the UK. I've been told by an immigration lawyer that as long as you have all your documentation to show that you have been exercising your EU treaty rights when you arrive at the airport they can give your spouse a stamp of residency for 6 months. Then once inside the UK, the full residence application has to be made.

If anyone has done this I would love to hear about it!

Thanks!

Comment: Was this an immigration lawyer you met somewhere, or was he giving legal advice to you as his client?

Comment: I contacted his company for advice.

Comment: You can also apply for an EEA family permit in advance, which might be less stressful than making the application at the border.